# Finding when a currently running Extended Events session started?

Tags: sql-server

For old-school traces, I can look in sys.traces or the SQL Server log to find when a trace was started. Is there something similar for Extended Events? I came across this [blog entry](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/logging-extended-events-changes/) about using a DDL trigger but I'm wondering if there is something better.

SQL Server 2012-2014

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is but it does not necessarily provide a "status" itself. If you look at the definition of `sys.dm_xe_sessions` in Books Online [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb630378.aspx):

> Returns information about an active extended events session. This
>   session is a collection of events, actions, and targets.

The key is `active extended events sessions`, this DMV is only going to return those XE sessions that are running. So you basically just look at the `create_time` and that is when the session was started. You can verify this by looking at the `system_health` session as the time returned should match up to when the instance was last started.

An example is my SQL Server 2012 instance on my local machine is kept stopped most of the time until I need it. I just started it so you can see the times are pretty close:
[image]

Comment: Things to consider for the above are that those events that end in $A are SQL Audits and that I have found the the create_time to not be reliable. I am looking at several create times right this moment where the extended event is indeed running but starts "19 days from now".

Comment: I've learned that SMO can you show both active and inactive sessions. It got added as a command in the dbatools module.

Comment: Have you since found a way to find non active sessions without SMO?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick code to check if specified Extended Event Session exists and if it is enabled or disabled:

```
DECLARE @xe AS VARCHAR(99) = 'AlwaysOn_health'
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.server_event_sessions WHERE name = @xe)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions WHERE name = @xe)
            PRINT 'XE "' + @xe + '" exists and it is currently enabled.'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'XE "' + @xe + '" exists but it is currently diabled.'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'XE "' + @xe + '" doesn''t exist. (check name)'
```

HTH.